# How to place the circle with 5KM radius with latitude and longitude coming from the API in leaflet open street map using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

In my angular project I have placed the map by using leaflet open street map.And I have to place the circle with 5km radius with latitude and longitude coming from the API.But I am unable place the circle .

I have fetched the Json array from the API and that is given below:

```
"Drone": {
    "Droneid": 1001,
    "latlong": [
        {
            "lat": 12.989839,
            "lon": 80.198822
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.051832,
            "lon": 80.194480
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.038453,
            "lon": 80.227442
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.009018,
            "lon": 80.242550
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.976903,
            "lon": 80.237056
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.956829,
            "lon": 80.193107
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.980917,
            "lon": 80.150531
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.007680,
            "lon": 80.149158
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.043805,
            "lon": 80.154651
        }
    ]
}
}
```

*From the latlong array elements(lat,lon) I have to place the circle of 5 km radius with index-0 elements(i.e first lat,lon values) and remaining are placed inside the circle.*

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
  constructor(private ds:DashboardService,private router: Router) { }
Drones:any;
  Droneid:string;
  latlong:any=[];
Drone:any;
var  map = L.map('map').setView([13.0827, 80.2707], 8);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
} ).addTo(map);
L.circle([this.drones.Drone.latlong.lat[0],this.drones.Drone.latlong.lon[0]],{radius:5000}).addTo(map);
```

```
dronedetails(){
  this.drones=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("drones"));
  console.log("drones",this.drones)
  console.log("array",this.drones.Drone.latlong);

}
```

I have tried but not showing any circle on map can anyone please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
L.circle([this.drones.Drone.latlong[0].lat,this.drones.Drone.latlong[0].lon],{radius:5000}).addTo(map);
```

instead of:

```
L.circle([this.drones.Drone.latlong.lat[0],this.drones.Drone.latlong.lon[0]],{radius:5000}).addTo(map);
```

You want the first elment in the `latlong` array

**Update**

```
this.drones.Drone.latlong.forEach((latlong, idx)=>{
    var latlng = L.latLng(latlong.lat,latlong.lon)
  if(idx === 0){
    L.circle(latlng,{radius:5000}).addTo(map);
  }else{
    L.marker(latlng).addTo(map)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks,Worked for me and can you please help me  to place the remaining latitude and longitude inside the circle in map.

Comment: Thank you so much @Falke Design it is working fine for me.

Comment: I have one more doubt in this,I have placed the drone icon with second latlong object,and remaining I have placed the markers in the circle.My task is to move the drone icon for each 1 ms from one lattitude,longitude to another coordinates.Can you help me regarding this.

Comment: Look at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-animations